# DEoptim appears to freeze in R

Tags: c, r, freeze, differential-evolution

I have encountered a situation where `DEoptim` appears to freeze. I can't figure out why and was hoping somebody with more experience in C could take a look at it.

It is rather difficult to create a reproducible example, so I simply saved the entire environment 50 iterations before the DEoptim freezes. The file below, `'Envir650.Rdata'` can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9O8SpdmUPxQV1ZOcHFQaEN1Umc).

```
rm(list = ls())
library(DstarM)
library(DEoptim)

load('Envir650.Rdata') # load the environment

# Adjust one function
argsList$fun.density = DstarM::Voss.density 

argsList$control$trace = 1 # show intermediate output
argsList$control$parallelType = 0 # don't use parallel processing
.Random.seed = randomseed # set seed

out = do.call(DEoptim, argsList) # freezes at iteration 21 and crashes R.
```

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: I hope the problem is now reproducible.

Comment: Can't replicate yet.  after `load()` I get `Warning: namespace ‘DstarM’ is not available and has been replaced by .GlobalEnv when processing object ‘argsList’`. Then `do.call` gives `Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : could not find function "getPdf"` ...

Comment: @BenBolker: that usually means the package isn't installed, but I cannot find DstarM on CRAN (I also checked the archives), nor via a Google search for "DstarM r package".

Comment: Apologies, I will provide an update soon. The DstarM package is still in the works and is not on CRAN yet. We encountered this problem with DEoptim while doing a simulation study to provide a quality check for DstarM.

Comment: The problem should now be reproducible, I would be happy if somebody could take a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in rtdists package, source file density.c, function integrate. The loop

```
for(x = a+0.5*step; x < b; x += step) {
    result += step * F->f(x, F->data);
}
```

becomes infinite because `step` is too small. It is so small that `x+step==x` and `x` never reaches `b`. The code of `integrate` should be changed so that `step` is never smaller than `EPSILON`:

```
--- orig/rtdists/src/density.c  2016-07-15 10:28:56.000000000 +0200
+++ mine/rtdists/src/density.c  2016-08-29 17:41:53.831078335 +0200
@@ -72 +72 @@
-   double step = width / N;
+   double step = fmax(width / N, EPSILON);
```

With this change applied, your example finishes at iteration 51 without looping or crashing. I've
[notified](https://github.com/rtdists/rtdists/pull/3)
the rtdists authors; the fix is now in the [github version](https://github.com/rtdists/rtdists) of the package.